# How to supply marker options such as rotate to \pgfuseplotmark?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I want to use a marker style for a node, so I'd like to have a bit of code like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node at (0, 0) {\pgfuseplotmark{halfcircle*}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If I want to rotate the marker (amongst other marker options), how would I supply the rotate option to `\pgfuseplotmark`?

Comment: Please post complete, minimal working examples. What you've given leaves any potential helpers to start creating one from scratch. And, as they say: solving problems is often fun; setting them up ain't.

Comment: @cfr Done, MWE added :)

Comment: Why can't you just say `\node [rotate=90] at...`?

Comment: @cfr Hmm. I guess a node can be rotated, but what about the size of the marker, for instance? A node can't be sized (apart from setting its minimum size) independent of its content, right?

Comment: Sure it can. `\node [rotate=90, scale=.5] at (1, 0)...`.

Comment: @cfr I guess that answers my question then? It seems that almost any marker option can also be a node option?

Comment: I can't say for sure because I haven't ever used the mark stuff, really. (Maybe once or twice.) So I'm not sure what options there are. But you can do an awful lot to nodes....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can rotate, scale, colour, make transparent... nodes...

[image: tweaked nodes]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node [rotate=90, text=red, opacity=.5] at (0, 0) {\pgfuseplotmark{halfcircle*}};
        \node [rotate=45, scale=2, text=blue, opacity=.75] at (.5, 0) {\pgfuseplotmark{halfcircle*}};
        \node [rotate=135, scale=.5, text=green, opacity=.25] at (1, 0) {\pgfuseplotmark{halfcircle*}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is a difference in the color where the halfcircle touches the outer ring circle. What do I have to do to get a consistent coloring?

Comment: @Hotschke You can use a `transparency group` but, unfortunately, it messes up the mark which is rendered with only a very thin circular boundary rather than one of the usual thickness. I'm not sure why....